# How to show a hidden DIV and auto hide it when other div is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a website which consists of  just one page (index.html), and inside this there are `divs` which basically will be used as pages inside the main page. I know we need jquery and or java to achieve this. But I am new to programming.

All I need is, there are about 8 divs (in other words, 8 pages in a single html file). I need to link those divs to the navigation bar navigations, and when I click on any navigation, the (hidden) `div` should come down like roll down effect. Also if I click some other navigation, then the currently opened `div` should automatically disappear and the new `div` should take its place.

Can anyone please help me. I am very new to these website buildings. If possible, redirect me to a video or some examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked for any libraries that might be designed for this?

Comment: yes i have tried lots of stuff but non worked. used libraries and some coding's around the internet.

Comment: you could try plugins (http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/) or simple put page contents in individual divs, asign them a classname and hide everything but the target div

Comment: You can look at tabs in JqueryUI library(https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hb7Za/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7", "div8"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
    if (visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
    } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
    }
    hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
    var i, divId, div;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if (visibleDivId === divId) {
            div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add onclick events to you links for the appropriate divs like this:

First link (displays div2 and hides all others):

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggleVisibility('div2');return false;">
```

Just repeat that link format with the other divs.

Comment: fishboy... need to ask you, the code you provided me? is there anyway you could add a transition effect to it? please add to the same code you provided. thanx :)

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2F2L/)

Navigation:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#foo">Foo</a></li>
<li><a href="#bar">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Pages:

```
<main>
<section id="foo">Foo's contents</section>
<section id="bar">Bar's contents</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main > section {
    display: none;
}
:target {
    display: block;
}
```

<sub>Be aware that `:target` pseudo class doesn't work on old browsers.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The animation requires jquery so the structure is different that my original answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>jquery slideup-down</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
.targetDiv {
display: none
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index).slideDown();
        jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 5</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 6</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 7</a>
<a class="showSingle" target="4">Div 8</a>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum5</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum6</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum7</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum8</div>  
</body>
</html>
```